# jpql query construction, value 1 did not match expected type

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jpa, jpql

Hello I have two tabel's

1.[Person table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRXIi.png)

2.[Phone numer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux6fx.png)

I'm trying to achieve such query

```
SELECT * FROM jobs.phonenumber where Person_ID='1';
```

but in jpql.

I was trying to make something like :

```
String query="SELECT p1 FROM PhoneNumber p1 WHERE p1.person=:id;
```

Here is sample of my entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "phoneId")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private int number;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Person_ID")
    private Person person;


@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "personId")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "personName")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "personAge")
    private int age;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<PhoneNumber> phones;
```

I have an error: Parameter value [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRXIi.png) did not match expected type [model.Person (n/a)]

here is my method:

```
@Path("{id}/phones")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers(@PathParam(value = "id") long id) {
    List<PhoneNumber> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    EntityManager createEntityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    String query="select p1 from PhoneNumber p1 where p1.person=:id";
    TypedQuery<PhoneNumber> createNamedQuery = createEntityManager.createQuery(query, PhoneNumber.class);
    createNamedQuery.setParameter("id", id);
    try {
        resultList = createNamedQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not retrive phone list");
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Could somone please help me with it, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use the `person.id` to query for:

```
String query="select p1 from PhoneNumber p1 where p1.person.id=:id";
```

or retrieve the person first and then use it as a parameter:

```
Person person = createEntityManager.find(Person.class, id);

String query="select p1 from PhoneNumber p1 where p1.person=:id";
TypedQuery<PhoneNumber> createNamedQuery = createEntityManager.createQuery(query, PhoneNumber.class);
createNamedQuery.setParameter("id", person);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below query:

```
  select p1 from PhoneNumber p1 where p1.person.id=:id
```

Comment: No don't do that. `createQuery` expects JPQL and there is no asterisk (*) in JPQL

Comment: By bad use from PhoneNumber p1 where p1.person=:id

Comment: Your bad again, JPQL starts with "SELECT {alias}"